# Zest2 into E4 application

Tags: eclipse-gef

I'm doing a project with E4 and JavaFX, I want to display a graph using Zest2 but following the example AbstractZestExample need a Stage and do not see how I can use the FXViewer without creating a new scene. I want to put the viewer in a SplitPane in a specified position of the application.

Answer (score 0):

By Alexander NyßenFriend

In GEF4 MVC 0.1.0, FXViewer was responsible for creating the scene, so that your use case can not be realized by using it. We have changed this for 0.2.0 (Mars.1), having exactly this use case in mind, so that the responsibility for creating the scene now lies within the responsibility of the client.

The respective changes to FXViewer are documented in https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/New_and_Noteworthy/3.10.1 (Fixed that FXViewer could not share a JavaFX scene) as well as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472646.